# Add graphics on a Jpanel Object with Thread

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-threads

I want to add graphics in this program. The graphics will be drawn on "drawPanel" object. I have to use thread here.

No idea for drawing in a Jpanel object with thread. What will be the good efficient way to draw graphics on that Jpanel Object?

How thread and `paintComponent()` going to interact.Thanks.

> Code:

```
public class LinearSearch extends JPanel{

    private final Font LABEL_FONT = new Font("courier", Font.BOLD, 30);

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JPanel inputPanel;
    private JPanel drawPanel;

    private JLabel lblTitle;
    private Button btnBack;

    public LinearSearch(JPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        initialize_All();
    }

    private void initialize_All() {
        lblTitle = new JLabel("\"Linear Search\"", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setFont(LABEL_FONT);

        ///Center Panel
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ///Input Panel
        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


        ///Draw Panel
        drawPanel = new JPanel();
        drawPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        /// I want to add graphics on this drawPanel Jpanel

        btnBack = new Button("Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setVisible(false);
                removeAll();

                mainPanel.add(new CatagoriesMenu(mainPanel));
            }
        });


        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        add(lblTitle, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnBack, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        centerPanel.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        centerPanel.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Comment: At what point, and how, does the app. do a *"Linear Search"*? I expect the most appropriate way to animate the progress of same is to draw the functional equivalent of a progress bar. E.G. a bordered rectangle stretching across most of the visual area, filled with a background color. Then fill a smaller (less wide) rectangle within that border representing the progress to that moment. For having searched 50 out of 150 records, it would fill a third. For 50 out of 100, one half. As to using a thread to do that, it would depend heavily on how you are using threads to search..

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Keep your questions noise free, so don't add stuff like "answer added".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must need to add graphics on "drawPanel" Jpanel Object.

Then you need to extend the `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent(...)` method to do your custom painting.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add this class object from another class in add() method.

> This will work (tested):

```
public class LinearSearchSimulation extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private final int DELAY = 50;
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    int x=0, y=0;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean threadFlag = false;

        public LinearSearchSimulation(JPanel mainPanel){
            this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        }

        public void start() {
            if (threadFlag) {
                return;
            }

            threadFlag = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (!threadFlag) {
                return;
            }

            threadFlag = false;
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.fillOval(x,y, 55, 55);
            g.dispose();
        }

        public void update() {

            x += 1;
            y += 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (threadFlag) {

                update();
                repaint();

                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
                sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

                if (sleep < 0)
                    sleep = 2;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                }

                beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

}
```